# Typescript data modeling shared by both front-end and back-end - Classes or interfaces?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, express

I wonder what's the best way of sharing the same data types between the client (React) and the server (Express + Socket.IO).

In my game I have different rooms, each room saves the current status, something like:

```js
class GameRoom {
    players: Player[];
    started: boolean;
    currentPlayerTurn; Player;
    dices: [number, number];

    constructor({players = [], started = false, currentPlayerTurn = null, dices = [1,1]) {
        this.players = players;
        this.started = started;
        this.currentPlayerTurn = currentPlayerTurn;
        this.dices = dices;
    }

    startGame() {
        this.currentPlayerTurn = this.players[0];
        this.started = true;
    }

    // etc..
}
```

The room is being generated in the server, being sent to the client as JSON, and then rebuilt in the client. I sync the data with socket events, and everything's perfect.

But there's a problem with the React side of the story: changing `GameRoom` properties won't cause a rerender. That means I have to `forceRerender()` each time something is edited, or listen to class changes. Both options are a mess and I [described it deeply in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61142978/make-a-react-component-rerender-when-data-class-property-change/).

This mess made me think maybe classes are not the best way to go. Using interface will solve this problem entirely, but I do lose instance functions like `GameRoom.startGame()`, that will have to be turned into utility functions, like:

```js
export function startGame(gameRoom: GameRoom) {
    gameRoom.currentPlayerTurn = gameRoom.players[0];
    gameRoom.started = true;
}
```

which is another mess, since they're hidden in code, and the developer **needs to know they exist**, and not edit `gameRoom` directly.

If you guys have any idea on how to model my data types, I'd be more than happy to hear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a functional approach. I'm not a huge fan of classes in JS.

Define a type for your game, but set the properties to readonly. This will tell the developer that they shouldn't mutate the GameRoom.

```
export type GameRoom = {
    readonly players: Player[];
    readonly started: boolean;
    readonly currentPlayerTurn: Player;
    readonly dices: [number, number];
}
```

Then, you can define all your changes as pure functions, so you define your inputs and create a new object that is your updated GameRoom. This makes things easy to test and track changes.

```
export function startGame(gameRoom: GameRoom): GameRoom {
    return {
        ...gameRoom,
        currentPlayerTurn: gameRoom.players[0],
        started: true
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use something like Redux and define your changes as a set of actions. (e.g. add-player, start-game, etc) Then, you can dispatch those actions from anywhere in your code.

The great thing about using immutability is every time you make a change to your object, you are returning a new one, so React will always re-render appropriately.

Comment: That's a nice approach actually, I have three questions:

1. will `...gameRoom` work in this case? because for example, it's like doing `players: gameRoom.players, dices: gameRoom.dices` - these are the same arrays, will it work with `readonly`?

2. What about efficiency when `gameRoom` have like 100 properties (some are complicated like other objects/arrays)?

3. Why `type` and not `interface`? Does it matter?

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, readonly works nicely with arrays. You can use the spread operator in the array to add a player. `...gameroom` will just apply all properties of `gameRoom` and only change the properties following. 

Efficiency is good, if you have a nested array or object that isn't changing, it will just add the reference to it under the hood, so you will only be creating new objects that have changed.

It depends on your use case for using a type or an interface. Interfaces are good for extensions, types are good for composition which works nicely with functional ideas like discriminated unions.